# Mixed design experiment: median reduction or linear mixed model?

Tags: mixed-model, nonparametric, multilevel-analysis

I collected data from an acoustic localization experiment with a mixed-design, where the factors are populations (one with hearing devices (HA) and one with cochlear implants (CI)), and conditions, four for the first population (with left HA, right HA, both HA, none HA), and three for the second population (with left CI, right CI, both CI). In each condition, there are 5 repeated measures for 13 collected items (target localization answers). Not all participants performed the test in every condition. I want to analyze differences within and between subjects and between populations in the respective conditions. Mixed ANOVA is not an option, even if it can accommodate missing data, because data is heavily skewed, and sphericity and normal distribution assumptions are violated. I see two possible options:

- reduce the repeated measures to a single value per condition per participant, via the median. In this case, some statistical power is lost. How can I compute and report the effect size or statistical power? Consider that with this reduction, the tests performed are not parametric.
- fit a Linear Mixed Effects Model, with random intercepts for subject ID. In this case, is a Q-Q plot with no straight line a violation of the necessary assumptions? Is the LMM a viable option if the relationship is more complex than linear? I would go in R, if the Q-Q plot is linear, with something like:

```
# Fit the mixed effects model
# - response: The dependent variable
# - population: Between-subject factor (2 levels)
# - condition: Within-subject factor
# - subjectID: Random effect for subjects

model <- lmer(response ~ population * condition + (1 | subjectID), data = data)
```

I analyze four different response variables: head distance, head rotation, signed error and unsigned error.
Outliers have been removed over the mean + 2*standard deviation (for each condition). Data has been transformed logarithmically.
The following are the Q-Q plots, histogram of the residuals, and residuals vs fitted values of the four variables. The skeweness values of the residuals of the four variables are respectively: 0.98, -2.69, -4.26, -0.58.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: *” How can I implement the code below in R if I have only one column named 'Condition' with all levels?”*. Not sure what you mean. You said there are 2 condition variables ? Can you expand on the description of your study design ?

Comment: @RobertLong Thank you very much for your interest. I edited the question and I hope is clearer now.

Comment: Thanks. You said *"data is heavily skewed"*. Do you mean the residuals are skewed ? We don't care if the response variable is skewed,

Comment: Not all the four response variables follow a normal distribution; the Q-Q plots represent some rather sigmoidal curves. The skeweness values of the residuals  are -0.58, 0.98, -2.69, -4.26. Outliers have already been removed (eliminating values over mean + 2*standard deviation for each condition) and data has been transformed logarithmically. For two response variables, the model could be applied. But I would like to consider also the comparison of the medians, to be able to apply the same analysis to all the four response variables.

Comment: OK, but are you are that it's not the distribution of the raw data that we care about ?

Comment: For what I understood, the assumption of the mixed linear model is that the residuals are normally distributed. And the skeweness values that I reported before refer to the residuals.

Comment: OK, so when you say *"because data is heavily skewed"*, are you referring to the unit-level residuals ? Could you show us the plot(s) please (just edit the question and add them).

Comment: @RobertLong I edited the question and added the plots.